# How to get the extended classpath of a Scala-macro-annotated class or object, in the macro?

Tags: scala, macros

If I've written a Scala macro that is to be applied to a Scala object or class, is it possible to get the extended classpath of that annotated entity, in the macro?  (I ultimately want it as a string, to be written by the macro to a file, for reasons.)

I need either the enclosing com.foo.bar package of that entity, or a way to directly get the extended com.foo.bar.MyClass classpath from the annotated MyClass.

Answer (score 0):

Well, not sure if it's the best way, but a solution that's working for me is to compile a "probe" class, using quasiquotes, using the context:

import c.universe._
   val probe = c.typecheck(q"""{class $$$$Pr0bE$$$$; () }""")

One can then ask for the owner of that "probe", which is a package in my case, and follow owners up to the "root", constructing the fully-qualified classpath of the annottee from that and the annottee's name.